# OSM Place Search in QGIS not working anymore?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8, nominatim

We've used OSM Place Search plugin daily with QGIS 2.2, 2.6 and 2.8 and it's been great.

However, it stopped working last week for myself and several other inter-office users. We enter search text, hit the arrow button and nothing happens. No error, no spinning wheel, nothing.

Here's the syntax from the qgis extensions log:

2015-09-22T16:27:30 1   http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?format=json&q=maywood%20park&addressdetails=0&polygon_text=1

2015-09-22T16:27:30 1   expected string or buffer

Anyone else experiencing this or any ideas how to fix?

QGIS 2.8 x64 on Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says: *The AppKey submitted with this request is invalid*.

MapQuest changed their licensing model. Since Sep 15th, 2015, they require a valid API Key for their services. For more information read the related [blog entry](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2015/08/17/mapquest-free-open-license-updates-and-changes/).

If the plugin doesn't offer a method for entering your own AppKey (or a custom Nominatim URL) then you will have to wait for the plugin to get updated.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, seems like until they get a way to authenticate, OSM Place Search Plugin is not at option.

But, the good news, is that Quick Finder plugin does as good if not better, for finding locations, including the whole OSM point locations, so you can search for things like "target tacoma" or "bar asheville" and you'll get point locations for those items that match the text.

We actually like it better than the OSM Place Search.

Answer (score 0):

open the nominatim_dlg.py file and eidt `getHttp()` function, as follow:

```
def getHttp(uri):
# http = QgsHttpTransaction(uri)
# content = QByteArray()
# if http.getSynchronously(content):
#     return str(content)
# else:
#     return None
r = requests.get(uri)
return r.text
```

before do this ,you should import `requests`